# PhoneGap Geolocation Not Working When Using Adobe PhoneGap Build

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I have taken the demo code below from the following link:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html

When I use Adobe PhoneGap Build to compile as an IOS device and install it on my iPhone nothing happens. All I get is "Finding geolocation...". I am never prompted to accept Location Services or see the Alerts execute.

My config files contains the following pertinent lines:

```
   <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.0.0" />
 <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />

<feature name="Geolocation">
   <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
    </feature>
```

Has anyone gotten this to work?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Device Properties Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for Cordova to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}

// onSuccess Geolocation
//
function onSuccess(position) {
    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
    element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude              + '<br />' +
                        'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '<br />' +
                        'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +
                        'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '<br />' +
                        'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '<br />' +
                        'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading               + '<br />' +
                        'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '<br />' +
                        'Timestamp: '          +                                   position.timestamp          + '<br />';
}

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
            'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
   </script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="geolocation">Finding geolocation...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Made the change to 3.0.0 in the script, it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

do you have the right cordova.js? i see that you have cordova-2.5.0.js the example docs are on 3.0.0

Comment: My config file has 3.0 referenced

Comment: @user1218244 but this is not 3.0 -> <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>

-SteinarLima i know, but i don't have the reps so i improvised.

Comment: I manage to get it working, but it only works if i set in Android - Location -> High Accuracy and with enableHighAccuracy: false option.